# SwiftUI attaching downloaded PDF to email message in iPadOS 14.0.1 fails

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My project calls for me to download a .pdf file, save it locally on an iPad and then craft an email message and send it.  Seems pretty straight forward.

Here's the code that does the download:

```
    func downloadFile() {

        let urlString = <private url>
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!

        
        let downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) {
            urlOrNil, responseOrNil, errorOrNil in
            // check for and handle errors:
            // * errorOrNil should be nil
            // * responseOrNil should be an HTTPURLResponse with statusCode in 200..<299

            guard let fileURL = urlOrNil else { return }
            do {
                let documentsURL = try
                    FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                            in: .userDomainMask,
                                            appropriateFor: nil,
                                            create: false)
                let savedURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
                
                try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: savedURL)
                try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: fileURL, to: savedURL)
            } catch {
                print ("file error: \(error)")
                self.text = "File Error: \(error)"
            }
        }
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
```

And here's the code that does the crafting of the email message:
(I followed this example: https://www.thetopsites.net/article/58693164.shtml)
(I've left out some of the boiler plate for brevity)

```
import SwiftUI
import MessageUI
//import PDFKit

//https://www.thetopsites.net/article/58693164.shtml


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var result: Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>? = nil
    @State var isShowingMailView: Bool = false
    @State private var text: String = "Foobar"
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isShowingMailView.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Mail Me")
        }
        .disabled(!MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail())
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingMailView) {
            MailView(result: self.$result)
        }
    }

struct MailView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    @Binding var result: Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>?

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

        @Binding var presentation: PresentationMode
        @Binding var result: Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>?

        init(presentation: Binding<PresentationMode>,
             result: Binding<Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>?>) {
            _presentation = presentation
            _result = result
        }

        func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                                   didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult,
                                   error: Error?) {
            defer {
                $presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
            guard error == nil else {
                self.result = .failure(error!)
                return
            }
            self.result = .success(result)
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(presentation: presentation,
                           result: $result)
    }

    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentsDirectory
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MailView>) -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        downloadFile()
        
        let urlString = "<privateurl>"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)

        let vc = MFMailComposeViewController()
        vc.mailComposeDelegate = context.coordinator
        vc.setToRecipients(["foo@bar.com"])
        vc.setMessageBody("Email Test", isHTML: true)
        vc.setSubject("email test")
    
        
        let docDirectory = getDocumentsDirectory()
        let filePath = docDirectory.appendingPathComponent("test.pdf")

        if let fileData = NSData(contentsOf: filePath) {
                 print("File data loaded.")
                 vc.addAttachmentData(fileData as Data, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "foo.pdf")
         }
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MFMailComposeViewController,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MailView>) {

    }
}
```

There's no file attached to the email message and I get this error:
`[PPT] Error creating the CFMessagePort needed to communicate with PPT.`

I haven't had any luck sorting this out.  If anybody can offer any thoughts, it would great.  Thank you.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue since you asked a solution for it?

Comment: @RolandLariotte I did ‘solve’ it by changing the design of the app to be less reactive.  That is, the .pdf is downloaded early in the process to give it time to arrive, vs. on demand and having the app pause while it comes.  There’s no difference to the user, but it’s poor design.